# APDU ISO 14443 Type B Authentification

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I have an ACR122U Reader and a command line tool to send and receive APDU commands. 
My Card uses ISO 14443 Type B.
ATR is 3B 80 80 01 01, T=CL, ATS = 05 77 77 81 02.

Auth Key is 6bytes of FF

How can i load the Auth Keys in memory and auth. to blocks?

Am now for days in google, tried many APDU commands. 
Thanks for your help!

And sorry, just starting here :-)

Comment: What card do you use? (The protocol does not indicate this. From your text I would guess MIFARE, but that uses type A...)

Comment: Attempted to read Android Beam with ACR Reader after 5 years, no luck